# TensorFlow: Predicting a value based on historic data

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, predictive-models, prediction, tensorflow

I'm trying to predict a dependent variable, which is a result of some independent variables. There may be a number of independent variables at play, but if I can approach the problem with 2 independent variables then I should be able to scale to include the rest.

Broadly, it's a resource problem. I have a required resource (z), which depends on time (x) and number of registered users (y). Registered users is a function of time, but I need the time component because the resource requirement is different at different times of the day. I want to be able to predict the resource requirement at a given time of day if our users continue to registered at a known rate.

Here is a chart of the data:

[image: Chart of the data]

How should I go about solving this problem? I've tried using TensorFlow's `DNNRegressor` estimator but with anything between 1 and a few thousand epochs, it still has a huge loss. This probably means I'm approaching the problem in the wrong way, right?

### EDIT

Sample Data:

```
Year    Month    Day    DayOfWeek    Hour    Minute    RegisteredUsers    Temperature    WindDirection    WindSpeed    Pressure   Target
2017      8      30         4         21       10            xxx             16.8            270              2         1014.9      1
2017      8      30         4         21       20            xxx             16.8            270              2         1014.9      3
2017      8      30         4         21       30            xxx             16.8            270              2         1014.9      2
2017      8      30         4         21       40            xxx             16.8            270              2         1014.9      5
2017      8      30         4         21       50            xxx             16.8            270              2         1014.9      5
```

Comment: Please post your actual data ...

Comment: @IrishStat please see my edit to the post. There are about 50,000 rows in total.

Comment: Probably tooooo much data ... I suggest using hourly data with less years ... say 3

Comment: @IrishStat smoothing the data isn't really an option, the distinction between 10:30am on a Wednesday and 11:10pm on a Friday is quite important for the thing I'm trying to predict. If I only know on a hourly basis, it won't be very effective for me. Is there a technique I can use to keep the nuances?

Comment: If short term ( i.e. within the hour) is important then to begin with it might be reasonable to limit the data to 3 months (90 days) .. thus 6x24x90 or 12,960 observations or even 30 days (4,320 observations) . As the Rolling Stones once opined "You can't always get what you want ...."

Comment: @IrishStat I understand that you think I need few observations, but wouldn't only considering the last 90 days mean that any seasonal trends (e.g. Christmas being busy) get lost?

Comment: yes & no   ... If you have 90 days of data you are not going to be forecasting Christmas meaning long term but rather the next few days taking into account trends developed for daily hourly forecasts. If there  are unusual observations in the past they will be assigned as exceptional/anomalies and will be neutralized via Intervention Detection. You can see by the non-response to your question regarding 50,000 rows that there is little one can do with that size problem other than "worry" or "complain" about inferior solutions.

Comment: @IrishStat so my `DNNRegressor` should work if I take, say, the last 90 days worth of data?

Comment: i don't think so ...because 1) there might be daily effects , there might be hourly effects , there might be interaction effects , there might be level shifts in the data , there might one of more trends in the data , there might br pulses/anomalies in  the data, hour-of-the-day effects might have changed over time, model parameters might have varied over time , model error variance might have changed over time. Make sure your software tests the assumptions premised by their model ... the statistical error is called" failure to validate the model's assumptions"

Comment: It is also called Model Specification Bias" see http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/01621459.1986.10478250 as there might be memory effects

Comment: @IrishStat Sorry, I'm a little bit confused now. My question is how do I approach forecasting my requirement based on the historic data? We've talked a lot about how much data I should use but I'm still not sure how to build and train a model which will let me forecast, based on whatever patterns and trends exist in my data.

Comment: You need to use software/methods that will identify the need for arima structure and also test for the deterministic effects that I have previously listed and also test for error variance constancy . These steps reflect an iterative solution-finding procedure culminating in a model that contains statistically significant parameters AND generates an error process free of identifiable structure. Your suggested tool is woefully inadequate when dealing with time series data , in my opinion. If you post 30 days of data I will try and help you further.